# convert date type(html5) to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

as you know in html5 we have got

`<input type="date" name="birthday" />`

but it will not supported in all browsers.
I need to use it in page and if the client browsers doesn't support it,make some calender by JavaScript instead of it.

how can I understand the browsers support it or not?
(I need to do it in client-side not by agent client in server side script by php)

Answer (score 2):

Testing whether the `input type=date` is supported is not hard. Create a container, and set the `innerHTML` to `<input type="date">`. Then, check whether the `type` attribute of the element is `date` (unrecognised values for significant attributes are ignored).

The implementation of the previously described method is shown below. It's a stand-alone function, and doesn't require any plugins or libraries. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aWYbZ/**

```
function isInputDateSupported(){
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.innerHTML = '<input type="date">'
    return d.firstChild.type == "date";
}
```

Comment: +1 But why not simply create the input element? http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/aWYbZ/1/

Answer (score 2):

The [Modernizr library](http://www.modernizr.com/) was created to help you detect which browsers support html5 features.

> Taking advantage of the new capabilities of HTML5 and CSS3 can mean
>   sacrificing control over the experience in older browsers. Modernizr 2
>   is your starting point for making the best websites and applications
>   that work exactly right no matter what browser or device your visitors
>   use.

Comment: Damn, you beat me by 37 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) JavaScript library does feature detection so you can easily adapt to different levels of support in different browsers. They also have links to "polyfills" which transparently port particular HTML5/CSS3 features to older browsers.